# Database Best Design (Confused between 2 concepts of design)

Tags: database, database-design, database-table

I am trying to design a relational database to manege two objects: residence and property.

a residence may have no property, one property, or many properties, and the property may not be related, but can only be related to a maximum of one residence (0:N relationship).

There are fields in common between the two tables: address, latitude, longitude and juridical_nature. In the case where a property is related to a residence, the value of the common fields must be identical to residence common fields value (same address, coordinates and juridical nature)

i am confused between two concepts

**Concept 1**

Each object table contains the common fields (address, latitude, longitude, juridical_nature). and i control the input by preventing the user to edit the property common fields and bringing the values from residence table

Residence:

```
residence_id|address|latitude|longitude|juridical_nature|residence_field6|residence_field7|residence_field8 ...
```

Property:

```
property_id|address|latitude|longitude|juridical_nature|property_Field6|property_Field7|property_Field8 ...
```

residence_property:

```
residence_id|property_id
```

**Concept 2**

Create a table for common fields and relate it to objects tables

Residence:

```
residence_id|common_fields_id|residence_field6|residence_field7|residence_field8 ...
```

Property:

```
property_id|common_fields_id|property_Field6|property_Field7|property_Field8 ...
```

residence_property:

```
residence_id|property_id
```

common_fields:

```
common_fields_id|address|latitude|longitude|juridical_nature
```

Which is the best and practical concept. and if there is another better concept would mind to share it with me

Comment: Why does a residence without a property have an address?

Comment: Concept  2 is a better solution.  You don't want duplicate information in your database if you can avoid it.  Duplicate information can lead to inconsistent information.

Comment: @Dan D without a property means that there is no property to sell. sold properties are deleted. the residence still exists and has an address

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc Thank you

Comment: Time to read a published academic textbook on information modeling & DB desgin.